# iPhone 6s backup and restore from iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

My iPhone 6S had an intermittent issue with the touch screen that was not responding to touch.

I backed it up using iTunes version 12.6.0.100 to my laptop.
iPhone was on version 10.2.1 when it was backed up.

iStore replaced the phone with one that also had 10.2.1 installed on it.

I tried to restore the backup to the new iPhone and got this message:

> iTunes could not restore the iPhone "xxxx" because the backup was
>   corrupt or not compatible with the iPhone that is being restored.

I took the phone and computer to the store and they loaded iOS 10.3.1 and said that this was the problem.

However, updating iOS did not fix the problem.

I still cannot restore the backup to the new iPhone. There is a lot of crucial information in some apps that I cannot lose.

It was suggested that I delete the backup and do a new one, however, as I do not have the old phone, I cannot.

What can I do at this point to restore the backup to my new phone?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for making sure to note all of the iOS versions and that you updated to 10.3.1 already, since that would definitely be my first suggestion.

I work on software called [Decipher Backup Repair](https://deciphertools.com/decipher-backup-repair.html), that deals with issues just like this. Sometimes there are glitches in the backup that cause it to be corrupt, and we fix those issues to make a version of the backup that is restorable in iTunes again.

Before getting to our software though, I would double check a few more things, such as trying a different cable, usb port, etc, just in case, if you have extras handy.